# Issue upgrading PloneFormGen on a Plone 3.3.1 migration

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I'm migrating a website from Plone 3.3.1 to Plone 4.3. The migration actually worked fine with no errors, but when I tried to update PloneFormGen to the current version (1.7.8), I get this:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 580, in installProducts
  Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 512, in installProduct
   - __traceback_info__: ('PloneFormGen',)
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 350, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
   - __traceback_info__: profile-Products.PloneFormGen:default
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1100, in _runImportStepsFromContext
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1015, in _doRunImportStep
   - __traceback_info__: pleonformgen
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.setuphandlers, line 79, in importVarious
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.setuphandlers, line 34, in update_kupu_resources
AttributeError: getPortalTypesForResourceType
```

Any thoughts? I saw something about Kupu having [old references to linkable types](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.plone.product-developers/3090), but I think this might be a different problem. I checked through my linkable resource types and they all seem to be the standard ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the "Resource Types" in the Visual Editor configlet on the Plone 3.3 side. Make sure it doesn't refer to any types that are either not installed or won't be available in 4.3. You may be able to eliminate the uninstalled types simply by saving the config.

And, make sure that PFG you upgrade to is 1.7.11+. There's a security advisory covering 1.7.8 and earlier.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I went back and unselected any odd entries in the 3.3 version, then redid the migration, but I get the same error. Thanks Steve! I'll keep poking around for what else it might be.